# Phabricator - Command failed with error #255

Tags: php, installation, daemon, phabricator

I have Phabricator installed on me, only it comes to this message:

> Usage Exception: Daemons are configured to run as user "phd" in configuration option `phd.user`, but the current user is "phd" and `phd` was unable to switch to the correct user with `sudo`. Command output:

As already to read in the message, Phabricator tries to start the daemons via the user phd (which I have set before in the local.json)! The joke is, that I execute that command (`php7.4 bin/phd start`) already as phd (also as to read in the message)... So I want to run the daemons as phd, Phabricator says it expects the execution from the user phd... But... Well... The error message doesn't really make sense! So what to do?

Comment: can you add the error message into this question, we can clearly see the problem if we don't know the error message detail

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sudo`. If it does not work, please try restart Phabricator.